# The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join, multiple-select-query

trying this

```
select tblPersonalInfo.companyname, tblJobBudget.title,tblJobBudget.lastmodifiedby,
tblJobAdv.advtitle, tblJobAdv.userId,       
tblApplication.advid, tblApplication.position
from tblJobAdv 
inner join tblApplication
ON tblJobAdv.advid = tblApplication.advid
inner join tblPersonalInfo
On tblJobBudget.lastmodifiedby = tblPersonalInfo.userid
```

gives error

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "tblJobBudget.lastmodifiedby" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "tblJobBudget.title" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
```

The multi-part identifier "tblJobBudget.lastmodifiedby" could not be bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because there aren't any table or table alias with `tblJobBudget` identifier.

Your tables are:

- `tblJobAdv`
- `tblApplication`
- `tblPersonalInfo`

But not:

- `tblJobBudget`

If you need columns from table `tblJobBudget` you should include `tblJobBudget` in tables with a `join` clause:

```
from       tblJobAdv 
inner join tblApplication
   ON tblJobAdv.advid = tblApplication.advid
inner join tblJobBudget                              <--here
   ON ...
inner join tblPersonalInfo
   ON ...
```

Comment: SELECT tblApplication.advid, tblApplication.scrdoc, tblApplication.position, tblJobAdv.advtitle, tblJobBudget.title, tblPersonalInfo.country, tblPersonalInfo.city,tblPersonalInfo.companyname
  FROM tblApplication 
  INNER JOIN tblJobAdv
  ON tblApplication.advid = tblJobAdv.advid 
  INNER JOIN tblJobBudget
  ON tblJobAdv.jbid = tblJobBudget.jbid 
  inner join tblPersonalInfo
  On tblPersonalInfo.userid = tblJobBudget.lastmodifiedby
  where tblApplication.position  = 'selected'